# .submit not firing with no <form> tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get a .submit event to fire off this input element

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphMaster$cphMainHeader$uc_search$ToolbarSearch" value="" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMaster_cphMainHeader_uc_search_ToolbarSearch" class="green-btn">
```

Its parent is

```
<div id="searchbox" class="box">
```

so there is no `<form>`

I've tried multiple combinations along the lines of

```
$('#searchbox :submit').submit(function(e){
    console.log('test');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But I can't get it to fire, any help appreciated

Comment: Uhm, only a form can be submitted, without a form there can't be any submit?

Comment: Your submit button has to be inside a form tag, it submits a form..

Comment: there is no <form> tags on this block at all (I didn't build the site) the text input works fine pressing enter or clicking the submit button

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a (now deleted?) comment

`.click` in combination with `.keypress` worked fine

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

> $( "#ctl00_ctl00_cphMaster_cphMainHeader_uc_search_ToolbarSearch"
>   ).trigger( "click" );

or

> $('#searchbox .green-btn').trigger( "click" );

hope it helps.